# modifying google ortools vrptw example fails

Tags: or-tools

I done some experiments with this exmalple:

https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrptw

My Data set is this:

```
 data['time_windows'] = [(0, 1), (0, 84), (0, 84), (0, 84), (0, 84), (0, 84), (12, 36), (12, 36)]

 data['time_matrix'] = [[0, 8, 7, 8, 4, 6, 8, 7], [0, 0, 10, 11, 4, 9, 8, 7], [0, 10, 0, 11, 4, 9, 8, 7], [0, 10, 11, 0, 4, 9, 8, 7], [0, 10, 11, 4, 0, 9, 8, 7], [0, 10, 11, 4, 9, 0, 8, 7], [0, 10, 11, 4, 9, 8, 0, 7], [0, 10, 11, 4, 9, 8, 7, 0]]
```

I want to have only one vehicle for a test. But if I set " data['num_vehicles'] = 1 " I get no output but a clean exit. Why? I guess this is just a standard TSP, if I reduce the vehicles to 1.

Comment: Can you check the limit on the dimensions are big enough ?

Comment: can you explain this in a few words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as mentioned by [Laurent Perron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9971759/laurent-perron) in the comment, there was a maximum time per vehicle in this example.

```
 routing.AddDimension(
    transit_callback_index,
    30,  # allow waiting time
    30,  # maximum time per vehicle            <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 
    False,  # Don't force start cumul to zero.
    time)
```

I changed it to a bigger number (99) and all the crap works very fine :)